# achieving pairwise combinations using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, tidyr

I'm trying to do all pairwise scatterplots of a single variable using ggplot2. Something similar to the default pairs(), but I'd like to manipulate the faceting and coloring with ggplot2. here is a failing example of my current attempt in ggplot2

```
iris_melt = melt(iris)
ggplot(iris_melt, aes(value,value)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(variable~variable)
```

[image]

What I would like is a plot of:

- Sepal.Length vs Sepal.Width
- Sepal.Length vs Petal.Length
- etc.

I know ggpairs from GGally would do the trick in this situation, however I'd like to do custom faceting and I don't see why I'd need to 'unmelt' the data instead of keeping it tidy

Comment: `Species` should be fixed?

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: I think melting the data frame is not the right choice while you should try with something like `ggpairs`

Comment: For an interactive analysis `library(rggobi); ggobi(iris)` could be an interesting alternative.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a built-in function

```
 library(GGally)
 ggpairs(iris)
```

Comment: I guess I'm trying to teach myself ggplot, and I thought that a 'tidy', or melted data frame was always the way to go. with ggpairs i need to 'unmelt' the data.

Comment: I understand that but this approach is suggested by the package author as well. Melting the data frame is sometimes very useful with `ggplot2` but this is not the case

Answer (score 2):

You can supply a custom function to `ggpairs` which allows you to control all the usual ggplot parameters

```
df <- read.table("test.txt")

upperfun <- function(data,mapping){
  ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping)+
    geom_density2d()+
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1.5,1.5))+
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1.5,1.5))
}   

lowerfun <- function(data,mapping){
  ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping)+
    geom_point()+
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1.5,1.5))+
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1.5,1.5))
}  


ggpairs(df,upper = list(continuous = wrap(upperfun)),
        lower = list(continuous = wrap(lowerfun)))
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720455/how-to-set-same-scales-across-different-facets-with-ggpairs/49929249#49929249) for the data and context

Answer (score -1):

Another post on stack overflow suggests that you enumerate the data, making an additional column for each comparison:

[Faceting plots by combinations of columns in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699084/faceting-plots-by-combinations-of-columns-in-ggplot2?rq=1)

This gets what I want, but its definitely not elegant when doing pairwise combinations between multiple columns.